# Transitions in Ising lattice gauge theories in 3+1 dimensions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, critical-phenomena, lattice-gauge-theory

What is known about the character of the transition (apart from the self-duality of the model and its self-dual point marking the transition point) in the Z2 lattice gauge theory in 3+1 dimensions?

Comment: I think the question needs more detail. Can you define the model, or at least provide a reference?

Comment: A definition of the model is provided by Eqs. (1.1, 1.2) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.09770.pdf (and, in more detail, in the classical review of John Kogut, https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.659?casa_token=Aa35fJ8UQZcAAAAA%3AI_jo7_cddGjMk6XHXFG_IeBANUL9hx49DSj2IH25gN6HaWjBhnHsOEZELLvtmVhAfcIo2IvEyyEJxyo (see Section V in particular)) . The four dimensional Ising gauge theory has a self-dual point. The question that I wish to know is whether the system harbors a critical or discontinuous transition.

Comment: I can't comment definitively, but I would strongly guess that the model has a critical (ie, continuous) phase transition. The general argument for area vs perimeter law holds (to my best knowledge) just as well for this model as it does for other lattice gauge theories with continuous phase transitions, such as the 3d lattice gauge theory (which is dual to the Ising model). This doesn't prove at all that the transition is continuous, but it would be quite shocking if it wasn't.

Comment: Thank you, Zack. I completely agree with your intuition and that was my first hunch as well. There were, however, some old  (>40 years) numerics that suggested a possible first order transition in 4D but others non-rigorously arrived, around the same time, at the opposite conclusion from general considerations.  Regretfully, I could not find anything definitive since but hoped that this has been looked (it is too natural a problem to have been left unanswered all of these decades) and was already part of the folklore. This was the origin of this question.

Comment: One generically expects any continuous phase transition between the confined and deconfined phases of a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ lattice gauge theory (with no additional global symmetries) to be in the co-called "Ising*" universality class, which has the same critical exponents as the Ising phase transition (mean-field exponents in 3+1D), but with some differences due to physical observable needing to be gauge invariant. See the discussion near the beginning of Chapter 4 (and Eq. 4.1) in https://www.proquest.com/docview/2457265155?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true

Answer (score 0):

The latest result on the model is by Malin Forsström:

["Decay of correlations in finite Abelian lattice gauge theories"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.03752)

which applies to finite Abelian gauge groups and in particular $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. It proves exponential decay of two point functions in some regime with regards to the coupling ($\beta\ge 0.4$ if I understood correctly).
To review the literature on rigorous results for Wegner's Ising discrete lattice gauge theory, one can look at the references in the article by Forsström, in particular the ones by Fröhlich-Spencer, Borgs and Chatterjee. One can also start with the article by Fröhlich-Spencer (covers $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ with $N$ large) and look up papers which cite it on say Google Scholar.